# how to split introtext in joomla?

Tags: php, joomla

I developed a module which can display article details as newsfeed. By clicking that article title user can go to the full article link.

this newsfeed display in main page. but it display the full content of the article.

I want to display only the first paragraph and if there are images it also.

I used here joomla content table introtext column data.

But i want to only display first paragraph and images only.

This is the code i used.

```
<?php
    $db = JFactory::getDBO();
    $db->setQuery("SELECT * FROM #__content WHERE catid = 8");
    $fullArticle = $db->loadObjectList(); ?>
    ..........
    <?php foreach($fullArticle as $article){ ?>
        <ul>
            <li>
            <h2><a href="<?php echo $article->alias;?>"><?php echo $article->title; ?></a></h2>
            <?php echo $article->introtext;?>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <?php } ?>
```

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a readmore into the article itself, or joomla considers the entire article is introtext. This is where you'll find the read more button which you can split your articles with, in the article editor:

[image]

Comment: yes i added. but it only display the title. i want to display first paragraph also.

Comment: You need to add the readmore after the first paragraph, or wherever you want the article to be split.